# Optimizing UNION

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

In MySQL 5.7 is it possible to optimize a query that coalesces values from three different tables? In pseudo-code something like:

```
SELECT id
  FROM table_1
 WHERE name = ?
  ELSE
SELECT id
  FROM table_2
 WHERE name = ?
  ELSE
SELECT id
  FROM table_3
 WHERE name = ?
```

At the moment I am using `UNION` in place of `ELSE` which according to `EXPLAIN` means I fetch from all three tables before noticing I only need the first row.

Comment: did you try this? SELECT COALESCE( (SELECT id FROM table_1 WHERE name = ?), (SELECT ...), (SELECT ...) )

Comment: Could it be that you _should not_ have names spread across 3 tables?

Comment: Is the "first row" necessarily the one from `table_1`?  `UNION` will not guarantee that.

Comment: @RickJames It is what it is at the moment. The application makes sure the name is unique across all three tables. In fact, this query is part of the code that checks uniqueness.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ... )` and check for "1".

Comment: @RickJames I also would like to know the ID if the name is already in use.

Comment: @vasily - Back to just the `UNION ALL` -- fetch all the rows; check that there is exactly 1 row and use it.  If not exactly 1, take other action.

Comment: @RickJames This is how it's done already. But I hope to find a solution where the second and the third queries in the union get skipped, in case the first query returns a value.

Comment: @vasily - You could put 3 selects and two `IF` statements in a stored routine, but it might be any faster.  Nakita's suggestion might come closest.